# stop div from reopening on click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, custom-data-attribute

I am fairly new to jQuery/JavaScript and I think I don't understand my own code.

It behaves exactly as I want BUT when I re-click on `.projtog`, it re-toggles my `.projContent` and I don't want that. I would like `.projContent` to close when I re-click on its associated `.projtog`. 
I tried giving .projContent a boolean value, but didn't really know what to do with it.

Here is my code:

```js
$('div.projContent').css('height', '0vh');

$('h2.projtog').click(function() {

  var $dataName_2 = $(this).data("name");

  $('div.projContent').css('height', '0vh');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#" + $dataName_2).css('height', '100vh');
  }, 290);

});
```

```css
#projectSection {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-top: 0;
  width: 45vw;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.proj {
  max-width: 40vw;
  color: #003c48;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.projtog {
  text-align: left;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.projContent {
  max-width: 40vw;
  max-height: 57vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
  position: relative;
}

.projectImages {
  max-width: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="proj">
  <h2 data-name="projectX" class="projtog"></h2>
  <h3></h3>
  <div class="projContent" id="projectX">
    <p></p>
    <img class="projectImages" src="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but... .projContent IS #projectX...

Comment: Oh, i think i see... you want successive clicks to not cause it to hide and re-show. In that case... you'll need a conditional of some kind to test whether or not the one clicked is the active one.

Comment: You could remove the `projtog` class at the end.  That way the event won't keep firing.  You'll have to rewrite the event slightly though as:   `$('h2').on('click', '.projtog', function() {...` and add `$(this).removeClass('projtong')`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div.projContent').hide();

$('h2.projtog').click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll(".projContent").toggle();
});
```

Above code will Toggle the `projContent` div.

Comment: You can further improve it by hiding the `projContent` div via CSS at page load like `.projContent{display:none;}`